# How to estimate coefficients for linear regression model on CEM matched data using `R` `cem` package?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm working on a project where we'd like to run a follow-up linear regression model on treatment-control data where the treatments have been matched to the controls using the `cem` package to perform coarsened exact matching:

```
match <- cem(treatment="cohort", data=df, drop=c("member_id","period","cohort_period"))
est <- att(match, total_cost ~ cohort + period + cohort_period, data = df)
```

where I'd like to estimate the coefficient and 95% CI on the "cohort_period" interaction term. It seems the `att` function in the `cem` package only estimates the coefficient for the specified treatment variable (in this case, "cohort") while adjusting for other variables in the regression.

Is there a way to return the coefficients and 95% CIs for the other regression terms?

Comment: You should not interpret the other coefficients in the model. They have no causal interpretation because you have not adjusted for their confounding. This is called the Table 2 fallacy. Only the treatment variable has an interpretable effect and CI.

Comment: @Noah So if I continue to use the `cem` package, would I have to specify `treatment="cohort_period"` instead of `treatment="cohort"` if I'm interested in measuring the cohort x period interaction effect (for a difference-in-differences study)?

Comment: @Noah Reading Westreich & Greenland's article on the Table 2 fallacy, I think my estimate of the cohort x period effect using the `MatchIt` and `Zelig` packages may still be unbiased. If I draw out a causal diagram for my project, it looks like: { period --------> total_cost <------------ cohort <---------- confounders } plus an additional arrow: { total_cost <--------- confounders } in the diagram. I think it's reasonable to assume whether an individual in my data falls in period=0 or period=1 is not related to confounder variable values like age, sex, etc.

Comment: Assuming this causal diagram is true, and since I'm not interested in unbiased estimates of the confounder variables, only cohort, period, and cohort x period,  I should be immune to the Table 2 fallacy, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Oh, I agree now. Sorry. I assumed you wanted it for other variables in the model. If you want the subgroup average treatment effect at each level of `period`, just make sure you do exact matching on `period`, include `period` in the PS model (if using one), and include the `cohort` by `period` interaction in the outcome model. I think you should be fine with your solution.

Comment: @Noah Thanks Noah. Should I match on `period`, or would that produce matched data subsets that all contain the same value of `period`, which wouldn't allow a regression to be performed on `period`?

Comment: Match on `period`. You'll still have different values of `period` in the overall sample, but pairs of individuals will come from the same `period`. You don't need to manually split up your sample into separate periods to do this. `matchit()` will do this for you with the `exact` argument.

Comment: @Noah Ah think I'm confusing subclassification (or blocking) with matching. Believe `MatchIt` can do both. But not sure how you can perform a regression on a collection of paired individuals (only 2 data pts per regression?). Hence I assumed you need to construct blocks of individuals from both the control & treatment cohorts and pre & post periods that share the same characteristics (e.g., all males, ages 20-29, etc.), then peform the `total_cost ~ cohort + period + cohort_period` regression within each block and find the aggregated regression coefficients with 95% CIs.

Comment: This is getting to be a different question than the one originally posed. I would be happy to answer in detail if you asked on CrossValidated.

Comment: Yes I'll write up a question on CrossValidated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I was using the wrong package - instead of `cem` I discovered the `MatchIt` and `Zelig` packages allow me to perform both exact matching and parameteric regression on the matched data:

```
library(MatchIt)
library(Zelig)

matched_df <- matchit(cohort ~ age_catg + sex + market_code + risk_score_catg, method="exact", data=df)
matched_df_reg <- zelig(total_cost ~ cohort + period + cohort_period, data = match.data(matched_df), model = "ls")
```